# How to only allow published content to appear on the front page?

Tags: nodes

I'm using the [`Scheduler`](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler) module to schedule when certain nodes get published & unpublished. They are set to be "Promoted to the front page" and even after the `Scheduler` unpublishes the content, it stays promoted to the front page where it still appears and leads to a dead link.

How can I automatically set the content to also get un-promoted from the front page when it gets unpublished?

I also submitted a [feature support request](https://www.drupal.org/node/2672500).

My front page is the default front page that comes with Drupal 7. I understand, that if I had my own view, I could select what kind of content gets displayed. But how can I do this with the Drupal 7 news feed?

Note: With mchar's suggestion, I came up with follwoing patch:

```
--- scheduler_orig.module   2016-02-20 12:52:02.002658565 -0800
+++ scheduler.module    2016-02-20 12:50:57.174657579 -0800
@@ -20,6 +20,20 @@
 define('SCHEDULER_DATE_LETTERS', 'djmnFMyY');
 define('SCHEDULER_TIME_LETTERS', 'hHgGisaA');
 
+/** [inserted by Ron 02/20/2016] -  to automatically unpromote a node as it gets unpublished**/
+/**
+ * Implements hook_node_presave().
+*/ 
+function my_module_node_presave($node) {
+  $was_published = !empty($node->original->unpublish_on);
+  $now_is_unpublished = empty($node->unpublish_on);
+
+  if (!$node->is_new && $was_published && $now_is_unpublished) {
+    $node->promote = 0;
+  }
+}
+/** [/inserted by Ron 02/20/2016] **/
+
 /**
  * Implements hook_permission().
  */
```

Comment: It depends on the way that you have developed your front page. Is it a view, a panel, a custom page, something else ?

Comment: @mchar please see **EDIT 1** above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know [scheduler module](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler) is not responsible for promoting or not nodes to the frontpage, so you have to go with a custom solution.

Try to implement [hook_node_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) as follows:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_presave().
*/ 
function my_module_node_presave($node) {
  $was_published = !empty($node->original->unpublish_on);
  $now_is_unpublished = empty($node->unpublish_on);
  
  if (!$node->is_new && $was_published && $now_is_unpublished) {
    $node->promote = 0;
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Cool! Do I understand right, that this hook will go into `scheduler.module` along with where the other hooks are and it will get invoked (by cron) when the nodegets unpublished?

Comment: Well, you have to create your own module and place that code in your module's `.module` file. Don't ever try to hack contrib modules or the core, [for many reasons](https://www.drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core)! Yes, the [hook_node_presave](http://%20https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) will fire whenever the cron runs. Here is a guide to create your [first module](https://www.drupal.org/node/1075072), don't be scared, it's really easy.

Comment: Cool yeah! But just following that tutorial didn't help, I had to create a .module file with an opening <?php tag. Otherwise it wouldn't show up in the modules list... hmm.

Comment: Create a my_module.info file and add these lines: `name = My custom module description = Description of my custom module core = 7.x`. Then create a my_module.module file and add: `<?php //your code`. Those files files must placed in `sites/all/modules/custom`. Enable your module and clear caches.